# Should I use a regex or a .startsWith() for my string operation?

Tags: regex, string, scala, pattern-matching

I need to segregate a sequence of strings on the basis of what string they start with. I have two options:

**Option 1**

```
val foo = """(foo.*)""".r
val bar = """(bar.*)""".r
myString match {
    case foo() => doSomething()
    case bar() => doSomething2()
    case _ => println("invalid String") 
}
```

**Option 2**

```
if(myString.startsWith("foo"))
    doSomething()
else if (myString.startsWith("bar"))
    doSomething2()
else println("invalid String")
```

Imagine I have five types of strings instead of two and I need to only match by how the strings begin. Which approach is better for my use case and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to choose: use a `match` with guards:

```
myString match {
  case _ if myString.startsWith("foo") => doSomething()
  case _ if myString.startsWith("bar") => doSomething2()
  case _ => println("invalid String")
}
```

The `match` helps visually to understand the structure, while `startsWith` is easier to parse visually than a regex for what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with match.

Tomorrow, you can add any `regex`(which can be more complex and not just match the start of the line) as another case which be will neater than an `if-else` ladder and also will be less error prone.

`If-else` ladder is imperative. A long ladder looks ugly and is just not the `scala` way.

But, in the end it comes down to taste. Performance wise, there will hardly be any difference.